# Can we use "soar" as a noun?

Tags: nouns, parts-of-speech

Is this sentence grammatically right:"In 2030, petrol and oil are expected to see **a soar** in its consumption and still maitain its leading position".

I have looked up the word "soar" in several dictionaries, some say that it is just a verb, but one says that it is also a noun.

Please help me to find if **Soar** is also a noun.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/soar
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/soar

Comment: I think you'd probably be better off writing the sentence with *soar* used as a verb:  "In 2030, petrol and oil consumption are expected to soar, maintaining their leading position."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The noun definition is found in many dictionaries.

> n.
>   1. The act of soaring.
>   2. The altitude or scope attained in soaring.
>  [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/soar)
>
> n
>   4. the act of soaring
>   5. the altitude attained by soaring
>  [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/soar)
>
> noun
>  1 : the range, distance, or height attained in soaring
>  2
>   : the act of soaring : upward flight
>  [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/soar)
>
> noun
>   6.an act or instance of soaring.
>   7.the height attained in soaring.
>  [Dictionary.com Based on the Random House Unabridged Dictionary](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/soar?s=t)

Cambridge Dictionary and Oxford Living Dictionaries don't list "soar" as a noun. These discrepancies between dictionaries are very common.

Comment: @Zebrasfish million thanks. It helps me a lot. have a good day!

Answer (score 5):

**Most certainly, it is a noun**.

The OED lists two such senses of ***soar***. Note that no lesser poets of the English Language than John Milton in *Paradise Lost* and Samuel Taylor Coleridge used it.

> 1. The altitude attained in soaring; range of flight upwards. Also fig.
>
> 1596   Raigne of Edward III sig. C1   Fly it a pitch aboue the soare
>   of praise.
>
> 1667   Milton Paradise Lost v. 270   Within soare Of Towring Eagles.
>   1792   S. Rogers Pleasures Mem. i. 361   That eye so finely wrought
>   Beyond the search of sense, the soar of thought.
>
> 1807   J. Grahame Poems 72   A splendid cloud appeared..; then
>   hovering, floats, High as the soar of eagle.
>
> 1892   Pall Mall Gaz. 26 May 7/1   It requires the highest soar of
>   fancy to imagine [etc.].
>
> 2. The act of soaring or rising high.
>
> 1817   S. T. Coleridge Satyrane's Lett. ii, in Biogr. Lit. (1882) 252 
>   A liberated bird..who now after his first soar of freedom poises
>   himself in the upper air.
>
> 1820   Scott Abbot I. xv. 315   It is ill whistling for a hawk when
>   she is once on the soar.
>
> 1870   D. G. Rossetti House of Life in Poems iv   Just when at that
>   swallow's soar Your neck turned so.
>
> in extended use. 1825   T. L. Beddoes Let. to B. W. Procter in Poems
>   (1851) I. 166   Wings upraise thee long In the unvacillating soar of
>   song.
>
> 1864   J. R. Lowell Fireside Trav. 306   There is none of the spring
>   and soar which one may see even in the Lombard churches.
>
> 1887   G. Saintsbury Hist. Elizabethan Lit. iv. 102   A little later
>   we meet with that towering soar of verse which is also peculiar to the
>   period.

Comment: Thank you so much. it's been a great help! have a nice day!